# Missing certain update (KB2999226 - aka UCRT) on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have Windows 10 and I get below error when trying to install certain software.

[image]

As far as I have read Windows 10 was supposed to have this update (or this CRT) already inside.

PS. When I click update Windows 10, it tells me it is up to date.

How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: That package is fror operating systems prior to Windows 10 (only).  So there is probably just something wrong with that specific software package.  Have you managed to successfully install this software on any other Windows 10 machines?  Are you using the latest version of the program?  Have you contacted the software's author about it yet?

Comment: I would agree.  Based on the poor grammar in the message itself.  This appears to be an error in the detection code itself.  *There is no way to install this update on Windows 10.*

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but with simplednscrypt, using windows 10 but missing "Universal C Runtime" (ucrt)
The solution was install "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017"
https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: This helps me but I used the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads